# How to create a strong name for referenced COM Interops

Tags: c#, com, interop, sign

In my project I want to reference a COM libraries from SolidEdge (CAD).

In the Reference Manager it's name is `Solid Edge Design Manager Object Library` and it's reference name in my Project is `Interop.RevisionManager`, but has no strong name.

So my question is, how to create a strong name for such COM lib's.

I guess I have to do it with tlbimp, but what is the `TypeLibName`? (Where to find the type library that appears as `Solid Edge Design Manager Object Library`)

Comment: COM doesn't really care about SNs.  Try adding a COM Reference to SolidEdge rather than a .NET reference to the intermediary interop dll

Comment: That is exactly what i did. I added a COM Reference to SolidEdge by selecting "Solid Edge Design Manager Object Library" in the Reference Manager.

Comment: Always, always favor the "Embed interop types" feature so you never need the interop library at runtime.  If you absolutely have to for some mysterious reason then use the /keyfile option that Tlbimp.exe provides.

Comment: Unless you are intending to SN your app, there is no need to SN something else

Comment: It's Framework 3.5 so the "Embed interop types" option is not available. And yes need to sign my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found that I can figure out the *.tlb file with the OLE/COM-Object viewer. And now I can create my signed interop with:
tlbimp revmgr.tlb /publickey:"MyKeyFile.snk" /out:Interop.RevisionManager.dll